Multiscreen by connecting using USB C
I just connected my laptop with another monitor using an external USB C cable. Unfortunately it is not working. I Connected my keyboard and mouse to external monitor, They work perfectly after connecting using cable. But the not able to share the screen. Please share solution if any one faced such issue.
Multi display is working fine for Windows!!

It's A dual booting setup. Windows is still working fine for Multi display.

I just tried second USB port and it worked :)
